# How to change the gravity of a TextView in another xml file from Main Activity?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an **XML** file that has a **TextView**, and I want to change its gravity from the main activity.
I used this code in the main activity:

```
// I just coppied the related codes 

TextView tvValue;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvValue = findViewById(R.id.tv_value); 

    // the tv_value id is from the (word_item.xml) file

}

private void OnClickFunc(View view) {
    tvValue.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
}
```

and the problem is that I get a **NullPointerException** error on a **null object reference**.
I know that I should somehow connect the xml file with the main activity.

word_item.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Word" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you and I appreciate your help.

Comment: post your on create method where you set the content view ie. `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: I just edited the question, please check again. thank you.

Comment: show your `activity_main.xml` file

Answer (score 1):

if you havent included the `word_item.xml` in your `activity_main.xml` then the error is obvious

so this is how you can include another file in any xml file in android

```
<include layout="@layout/word_item.xml" />
```

then things ll work as you expect

Answer (score 1):

Try to first inflate the other layout as follows the initialize the view

`LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this); final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_item, null);`

Then

`Textview tvValue = findViewById(R.id.tv_value);  private void OnClickFunc() { tvValue.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);`

Answer (score 0):

Where did you initialize textView variable?? Variable must be initialize after setContentView in OnCreate method in Activity.